# CSS applying style to individual element rather than the class

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a responsive table.  Everything works the way I like except one major bug.  When I load the grid on a small window and then expand the window, the table doesn't expand with me.  However, if I load it on a larger window and then shrink it down, it responds as I expect and then expands as I expand the window.  The way it works is that I have table cells labeled with classes of "optional" or "essential" and optional columns get dropped as the screen size goes down.

After stepping through the CSS and Javascript, I found out what's wrong, but not sure what's causing it.  When I load the table on a larger screen, the css style "display: none" is being applied to the "optional" class like:

```
.optional { display: none; }
```

This all works.

However, when I load the table first on a smaller window, the style is applied inline, like:

```
<td class='optional' style='display: none'>...</td>
```

This is where it breaks, since the style is applied so specifically, none of my logic for showing the element has any effect.  Is this some weird bug in CSS?  Has anyone come across this before?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: SOLVED

Thanks for the quick responses and the great help.  Ultimately, the problem lay somewhere else in the code that wasn't really even related to my question.  I appreciate all the help though.

Comment: If the `style='display: none'` is not in your html before loading it into the browser and not being added in from backend code, this will be (most likely) being applied by JS on page load. You could try loading the page with JS turned off to see if this is the case.

Comment: Could you post a fiddle or jsbin link with the demo? Otherwise, it is very difficult to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

To make it respond when you make the window bigger you might consider adding an window resize event handler and calling a function to resize the table when the window is resized. If you like this option I will post the code.

**EDIT:**
Code:

html:

```
<body onload="window.addEventListener('resize', setTable); setTable();">
```

javascript:

```
function setTable()
  {
    var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    document.getElementById('yourTable').style.width = windowWidth+'px';    
//You may adjust this because for all I know there are other elements surrounding your table
  }
```

Comment: This is more what I'm looking for.  I have some other javascript functions that setup the table as a reusable component and allow a user to check and uncheck columns to show at any screen size, so I think a javascript solution would be best.

Comment: I have done something similar on my website. www.socialize24.com

Comment: take a look at the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will solve your problem, but you forgot the ";" sign in your code:

Wrong:

```
<td class='optional' style='display: none'>...</td>
```

Correct:

```
<td class='optional' style='display: none;'>...</td>
```

Comment: sorry.  Typo.  It's in the code right, I just mis-typed

Answer (score 0):

I would drop the javascript and just use media queries.  Media queries can go inside your css file.

```
.optional {
    display: none;
}
@media (min-width:980px) {
    .optional {
        display: table-cell;
    }
}
```

This will make optional's css change whenever the screen is larger than 980px.  You will avoid the inline styling that the javascript is adding.